# How to implement effective two way communication with service worker and client web page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, service-worker, service-worker-events, message-channel

I want to implement effective 2 way communication between service worker and client web page.

here is my code

```
    function twoWayMsg() {
    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        var messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
        messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("Response the SW : ", event.data.message);
        }

        console.log("Sendingage to the service worker");
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
            "command": "twoWayCommunication",
            "message": "Hi, SW"
        }, [messageChannel.port2]);
    } else {
        console.log("Nove ServiceWorker");
    }
}
```

and

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    var data = event.data;

    if (data.command == "twoWayCommunication") {
        console.log("Respondingessage from the Page: ", data.message);
        event.ports[0].postMessage({
            "message": "Hi, Page"
        });
    }
});
```

is it good to create MessageChannel object each time?

if i use global variable for message channel object , then am getting this error

```
 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'ServiceWorker': Port at index 0 is already neutered.
Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'ServiceWorker': Port at index 0 is already neutered.
```

Comment: No luck finding a solution? I just tried the same thing and clearly the browser doesn't like it as I am getting the same message.